# SharePoint Error "Error converting data type varchar to numeric." on "Single line of text" column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error, column

I have a column defined in SharePoint as "Single line of text"  when I deploy my webpart, and try to enter text in the field I get the following error from my log file:

"Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

This works in my development environment, but not in my production.  I have triple checked my column type, but still get this error.  I am able to enter numeric values in the field and it saves just as desired, however when I try to enter text I get the error.

I may have once had the column defined as number, and changed it to "Single Line of text".  I'm afraid it's holding on to the previous column type definition.

Any ideas?

Comment: could you please share the complete logs n also code / screenprint where you declare column.

Comment: Try this: Go to the field edit page by clicking on the field in SharePoint UI. Change nothing and just click OK (Make sure "Single Line Of Text" is selected). CLICK OK not cancel.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the field and creating it once again?